# How is asking for a previous password a good practice?

Tags: passwords

Since data leaks are being more and more common, why companies like Microsoft and Google (but I'm not asking just about them) ask for a previous password if a user try to recover it?

Google's password recovery step:

> Enter the last password that you remember using with this Google
> Account

Why should we change our passwords frequently if their servers are storing the old ones and asking for them even with the possibility of it be leaked?

Comment: When do they ask for the previous password? I can't envision what you are talking about. You mean when you want to change your password?

Comment: "changing your password frequently" is also not good practice and advice has been to stop doing that, unless you are changing them to strong passwords each time (without some kind of a pattern)

Comment: If you forgot your password, the first step of they recover policy is ask for the newest password that you remember. This question seems like they know your previous passwords.

Comment: Well, at best, they know the ***hashes*** of your previous passwords, right?

Comment: But this hashes could be decrypted, am I wrong?

Comment: Not decrypted, no. You would have to brute force the hashes.

Comment: So, the current password hash and past passwords are in the database. The database gets leaked. How are the old passwords a greater threat?

Comment: I also suggest that you might be assuming that they store the old passwords. Perhaps they do not and the prompt is to see if you remember your ***current*** password. If you fail, they can still continue with the process, if you succeed, then they can cut the process short.

Comment: @schroeder If a previous password is leaked and someone try to use it to "recover" the actual password, the hacker could get some advantage, no?

Comment: ... Um, if they have the password database, then they have the actual real password ... And ok, let's say that an older password is easier to crack than the current password, so it gets cracked first. You are making an assumption that the knowing an old password somehow gives an advantage.

Comment: Having gone through this before myself, I think it may help to realize this is only *part* of their recovery process.  Moreover, the details of the recovery process vary wildly based on what they know about you and how certain they are you aren't an attacker.  If you are using the same device/IP you always use, they ask some simple questions, and based on the overall "score" of your response, they decide whether or not to grant access.

Comment: If you were connecting from an unknown device on another continent, it definitely will not be as simple as "Oh, you know an old password, sure here you go!" (nor is it even that simple for trusted devices).  In short they are trying to find a good balance between "secure" and "easy for the user", which is the best that anyone can do